# panic: runtime error: index out of range 1

Tags: go

i can not figure out this problem ,anyone can help?

panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /root/go/src/k8s.io/client-go/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration/test_json.go:15 +0x42

```
type obj struct {
    Targets [2]string  `json:"targets"`
    Labels  map[string]string `json:"labels"`
}

func main() {
    // Creating simulation
    var myobj = []*obj{}
    n := new(obj)
    myobj[0].Targets = [2]string{"10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"}
    myobj[0].Labels = make(map[string]string)
    myobj[0].Labels["job"] = "db2"
    myobj = append(myobj, n)
    k := new(obj)
    myobj[1].Targets = [2]string{"192.168.1.12", "192.168.1.13"}
    myobj[1].Labels = make(map[string]string)
    myobj[1].Labels["job"] = "mysql"
    myobj = append(myobj, k)

    // Converting to JSON, for transmission over web
    data, err := json.Marshal(myobj)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

finally i figure this out XD!

```
type obj struct {
    Targets []string  `json:"targets"`
    Labels  map[string]string `json:"labels"`
}

func main() {
    // Creating simulation
    var myobj = []*obj{}
    n := new(obj)
    n.Targets = append(n.Targets, "10.0.0.1")
    n.Labels = make(map[string]string)
    n.Labels["job"] = "db2"
    myobj = append(myobj, n)
    k := new(obj)
    k.Targets = append(k.Targets, "192.168.1.12")
    k.Targets = append(k.Targets, "192.168.1.13")
    k.Labels = make(map[string]string)
    k.Labels["job"] = "mysql"
    myobj = append(myobj, k)
```

Answer (score 1):

You create an `obj` n, then do nothing with it until you try to append it. So there are no `obj`s in `myobj` yet.

```
var myobj = []*obj{}
n := new(obj)
n.Targets = [2]string{"10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"}
n.Labels = make(map[string]string)
n.Labels["job"] = "db2"
myobj = append(myobj, n)
k := new(obj)
k.Targets = [2]string{"192.168.1.12", "192.168.1.13"}
k.Labels = make(map[string]string)
k.Labels["job"] = "mysql"
myobj = append(myobj, k)
```